# How to set Image in background of Floating action button instead of color in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying set floating action button in android app. But here i want to put image background instead of colors or drawable in floating action button. 
Here can't upload image because i am not eligible to upload image so, i am posting image link. it is from google design document...

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B1PhAWhtrRTrenZ5RnRTMmEtcU0/patterns_actions_fab_actions14.png

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you !!

Comment: Make confirmed first that do you want to upload or put/set image to FAB?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem
Try removing tint property

Answer (score -2):

apply background tint and your icon

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
...
app:backgroundTint="@color/your color"
android:src="@mipmap/your icon" />
```

the result will be colored button with an icon.Note that app namespace is used